# React-Native Android Emulator Not Launching in Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

**I don't know what to do anymore, The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_30 has terminated. I did uninstall it and install it, didn't fix anything**

**this is the log :**

better view in log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov49X.png)

2023-05-26 20:52:37,756 [ 562975]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 30 -
C:\Users\oussama\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_XL_API_30
2023-05-26 20:52:37,785 [ 563004]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 30 - Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
2023-05-26 20:52:37,785 [ 563004]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 30 - Found systemPath C:\Users\oussama\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86
2023-05-26 20:52:37,801 [ 563020]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 30 - Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
2023-05-26 20:52:37,801 [ 563020] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)